# Adding a quantity field to list.phtmls layout

Tags: magento2, quantity

I want to give my customer the possibility to enter the desired quantity on the category page itself.

How can I do that? Adding a quantity field simply puts it on there, but it has no function.

[image: I want the qty field right to the left of this button]

Comment: Refer http://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-qty-increment-buttons-to-product-page/
http://surajviradiya.blogspot.sg/2015/09/add-increase-and-decrease-quantity.html & Use

Comment: The question is about qty forms on the category page, not increasing buttons for the product page.

Comment: This is just for reference. You have to take idea & implement